# ATI graphics card: Is proprietary firmware needed in any case?

Tags: drivers, ati, firmware

I am trying for days now to enable 3d of my ATI X 1900 under Debian GNU/Linux 7.6. I installed the xserver-xorg-drivers-radeon package, however this does not work. Specifically, I receive a similar error message as the user here: [How to configure FOSS ATI drivers on Debian Wheezy and ATI RS880 [Radeon HD 4250]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39024/how-to-configure-foss-ati-drivers-on-debian-wheezy-and-ati-rs880-radeon-hd-4250)

This is (drivers names etc. below are not mine, but similar):

```
[    8.121829] [drm] Loading RS780 Microcode
[    8.156063] r600_cp: Failed to load firmware "radeon/RS780_pfp.bin"
[    8.156092] [drm:r600_startup] *ERROR* Failed to load firmware!
```

The hint usually given in the internet is to install the firmware-linux-nonfree package.

So my question is: Do you in any case have to install proprietary firmware, even when using free dirvers? Isn't it possible to stay completely free?